# How to Connect my Users to a custom post type I Labelled Campaign

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I’ve created a Custom Post Type Name 'Campaigns' and now, I would like the users of my site (only registered ones) to indicate their interest in promoting the campaign by just clicking the promote on each campaign single page. On the campaign page, they would just click on "Promote" button and they would be associated with the camp (no need for tickets, payment, …). I have no clue on where to look at to implement that (taxonomies, meta, …, ?) and how this will be stored (on user entity, on event custom post type entity)? I need help!

Comment: note that there may not be a single correct answer for this, and you need to be able to mark a single answer as _the_ official canonically correct answer, not just the most useful response

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update_user_meta` function in WordPress to store information about the user's interest in promoting a campaign

```
// Assuming $user_id is the current user's ID and $campaign_id is the ID of the campaign.

update_user_meta($user_id, 'promoted_campaigns', $campaign_id, true);
```